# Slow Oracle query

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle8i

I am building a web application for a customer and I have a problem with a particular SQL query.

The query is:

```
select order_header.order_no,
       order_header.purchase_order_no,
       order_header.entry_date,
       order_header.delivery_date,
       order_totals.total_quantity
from   order_header,
       order_totals
where  order_header.order_no = order_totals.order_no
```

I have done some troubleshooting and this:

```
where  order_header.order_no = order_totals.order_no
```

is the problem. The SQL query with this line takes 35 seconds (causes DataTables to even time out at times) and without it it is instant.

So, I know the problem but I'm not a DBA so don't know the solution.

It's not my database, so the solution I need to send to the DBA to sort so I can continue with my job. Something like

> "Hey, would you mind doing A on B table so that C speeds up?"

I just don't know what actually needs to be done!

Comment: Have you investigated the query execution plan ? Is there an index on `order_header.order_no` or `order_totals.order_no` ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Hi. Looking at the table list their DBA sent at the start, `order_header.order_no` has `Unique Index` but `order_totals.order_no` has nothing ...

Comment: Are you sure the second option is 'instant'? Just printing out the results should take a long time, considering how long the original took.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh 1.5 seconds without line. 35 seconds with line.

Answer (score 1):

First add an index on both order_header.order_no and order_totals.order_no and check that both the columns are of the same type.
For other optimizations we should talk about the data.
Don't forget to update the statistics

Answer (score -1):

Ask your DB to

**add an index on the order_no column in both order_header and order_total**

That should help with your current problem.   Also, look up JOIN and change your query to use the JOIN syntax.

```
 select order_header.order_no,
           order_header.purchase_order_no,
           order_header.entry_date,
           order_header.delivery_date,
           order_totals.total_quantity
    from   order_header 
    join   order_totals ON order_header.order_no = order_totals.order_no
```

Comment: Hi. They use Oracle 8i, I think it's not possible or something. I remember something about 8i. Thanks for other answer :-)

Comment: Having an index on both tables instead of only one will probably only replace the *table full scan* by an *index full scan*. Does that can really make a big improvement?

Comment: Sylvain Leroux, are you seriously asking this question???
If you don't know the difference between table scan and index scan then you should not comment on this answer.